# Minecraft bukkit zombie-spawning error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am writing a simple zombie-spawning plugin. The spawning is done by another thread. When I run the plugin, I get the following error after some time of playing:

```
[Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
 at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_25]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.EntityTracker.updatePlayers(EntityTracker.java:152) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:646) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedServer.u(DedicatedServer.java:250) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:545) ~[craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:457) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
 at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:617) [craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.3-b3020jnks]
```

This error continues to occur, but it occurs rarely and it seems random. My thoughts to this problem are that the spawning-thread is asynchroune to the EntityTracker, which leads to a exception because my thread modifies the entity-list while another part of bukkit tries to tell the players the positions of the monsters.
I don't have any idea what the exact error-source is, but I think I have to synchronize my thread with some part of bukkit. Does anyone have a solution for that? (And is there any way to set the items which a zombie will drop? The whole rotten flesh is starting to give me nightmares).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue probably is that you're modifying some `HashMap` while you're iterating over it, just as the stack trace implies.

Comment: @user3580294 I already mentioned that: `[...] exception because my thread modifies the entity-list while another part of bukkit tries to tell the players the positions os the monsters`. But you're right, I didn't say it that way.

Comment: Might want to look into Java's `ReadWriteLock` then. If done properly, you should be able to have multiple readers, but if a thread is writing no other thread would have access to the `HashMap`.

Comment: @user3580294 That is the problem: I don't know how to "find" this HashMap, because it's an attribute of an API-class. So I can't access this HashMap (or at least I think so) and I don't whether I can rely on that HashMap or not.

Comment: the stack trace has it: `EntityTracker.java`, line 152, in the `EntityTracker.updatePlayers()` method. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be a `HashMap` you're supposed to be modifying though... If that's the case, I'm not sure I can help you too much because I'm not familiar with Bukkit's API. Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stacktrace is saying that you are trying to modify your collection from another thread.
You could either try to synchronize your methods or use something like a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

If you don't really need the modification to be on another thread, you could also use Bukkit's schedule facility to do the job :

```
private final Map<T> map = new HashMap<T>();
// ... stuff happens

final T value;
// work with your value

server.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        map.add(value);
    }
}, 0L);
// runs the run() method after 0 ticks on the main thread
```

Comment: I'm not trying to modify my HashMap from another thread, if this would be the case I would use `synchronized` or something from the java-library, but I don't modify the problematic HashMap directly (just by using `world.createEntity(...)`) and I don't know how to find this HashMap.

Comment: @Sirac if you cannot access the hashmap directly, you NEED to use the scheduler to call world.createEntity(). Doing so will ask bukkit to run the thread-unsafe code on the world thread.

Comment: This solution sounds rather unhandy to me (maybe just because I have my code in mind). Don't you think there is another way? That would be great? (btw. do you know, how other plugins do this?)

Comment: @Sirac on all the plugins I've done and seen, all the api calls that are not thread safe must be done on the world thread using the scheduler. There is no other way that I am aware of given the current informations, other than making a whole new scheduler yourself, which kind of defeats the purpose, sorry. Do you have a code sample to show, maybe ?

Comment: After some research I have to admit that your way is the only way to do things. At first I hesitated, because you created a new Runnable, which accessed a private attribute. This interfered with my general programming style, but after some time I had the idea, to make my Thread itself a `BukkitRunnable`, which can be called repeatly after a specified amount of ticks, similar to the way you suggested.